# Setting TTabControl color after XPManifest in Delphi

Tags: delphi, properties, components, colors, tabcontrol

I have tabcontrol component on my form. After I put XPManifest, its color became white, I want to change it, but couldn't find color property. And I don't want to remove XPManifest as well. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the color of a TTabControl must put the **OwnerDraw** property to true  <strike>false</strike>  and write your own code to draw the tabs and  the background in the **OnDrawTab** Event.

see this example.

```
procedure TForm38.TabControl1DrawTab(Control: TCustomTabControl; TabIndex: Integer; const Rect: TRect; Active: Boolean);
var
y    : Integer;
x    : Integer;
aRect: TRect;
begin
  if Active then
  begin
    //Fill the tab rect
    Control.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWebGainsboro;
    Control.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);        
    //Fill the background
    aRect.Left:=1;
    aRect.Right:=Control.Width-1;
    aRect.Bottom:=Control.Height-1;
    aRect.Top:=Rect.Bottom+1;
    Control.Canvas.FillRect(aRect);   
  end
  else
  begin
    //Fill the tab rect
    Control.Canvas.Brush.Color := clBtnFace;
    Control.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);
  end;

  y  := Rect.Top + ((Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top - Control.Canvas.TextHeight(TTabControl(Control).Tabs[TabIndex])) div 2) + 1;
  x  := Rect.Left + ((Rect.Right - Rect.Left - Control.Canvas.TextWidth (TTabControl(Control).Tabs[TabIndex])) div 2) + 1;
  //draw the tab title
  Control.Canvas.TextOut(x,y,TTabControl(Control).Tabs[TabIndex]);
end;
```

Comment: I have just noticed interesting thing: The OwnerDraw property actually was False, probably that's why it is white. When I put it to True, the background color becomes correct, but the tab captions become invisible O_o.. Can you comment on that?

Comment: This procedure works fine, thanks. One thing I should notice also is that it only works when OwnerDraw it TRUE, not FALSE. When OwnerDraw is false, OnDrawTab is not called.

Comment: @Tofig: Correct, OwnerDraw instructs the control that it needs to call  OnDrawTab to draw itself.

Comment: Corrected, Ownerdraw should be true.