# Delphi create custom PageControl with a different background color

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I read that the best way to change the `PageControl` color would be to create a new Delphi component named `CustomPageControl` that functions the same as `TPagecontrol` but has a different background color but after doing that nothing has changed it's like I am still using the old `TPageControl`.

```
unit CustomPageControl;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Controls, ComCtrls, Graphics, Messages;

type
  TCustomPageControl = class(TPageControl)
  private
    FBackgroundColor: TColor;
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property BackgroundColor: TColor read FBackgroundColor write FBackgroundColor default clSkyBlue;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

constructor TCustomPageControl.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  FBackgroundColor := clSkyBlue;
end;

procedure TCustomPageControl.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;

  if Message.Msg = WM_PAINT then
  begin
    Canvas.Brush.Color := FBackgroundColor;
    Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
  end;
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Custom', [TCustomPageControl]);
end;

end.
```

MainMenuForm :

```
uses
  ... CustomPageControl;

PageControl1: TCustomPageControl;
```

Comment: Thanks for informing us. Also: similar to [Changing active page's tab color and having it reset after clicking on another tab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65748489/4299358).